# Object references problem

Tags: c#, class, reference, copy

My question is going to be quite consistant.

I have a generic class `Cell<T>`. And I have client class which operates with 2dimensional array of `Cell<T>`:

```
public sealed class Environment
{
    private Cell<YUV>[,] primaryLayer;        

    public Colorizator(Cell<YUV>[,] layer)
    {
        // initialization...
    }
// ...
}
```

In the `Environment` class I call method that makes following:

```
for(var ix = 1; ix < this.Width - 1; ix++)
{
    for(var iy = 1; iy < this.Height - 1; iy++)
    {
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[0] = this.primaryLayer[ix - 1, iy + 1];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[1] = this.primaryLayer[ix, iy + 1];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[2] = this.primaryLayer[ix + 1, iy + 1];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[3] = this.primaryLayer[ix + 1, iy];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[4] = this.primaryLayer[ix + 1, iy - 1];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[5] = this.primaryLayer[ix, iy - 1];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[6] = this.primaryLayer[ix - 1, iy - 1];
        this.primaryLayer[ix, iy].Window[7] = this.primaryLayer[ix - 1, iy];
    }
}
```

It fills each cell Moore neighbourhood with neighbour.

Then I use algorithm similar to flood fill in other method:

```
foreach(var cell in some_list)
{
    Parent = cell;
    Parent.Conquer(Parent);
    Parent.ViabilityRatio = this.ViabilityTresholds.Max;

    lr[Parent.X, Parent.Y] = Parent;

    while(true)
    {
        if(null == (Child = Parent.Window.FirstOrDefault(x => !(x as Cell<YUV>).IsMarked) as Cell<YUV>))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Parent.Mark(Child);               

            var wt = default(Double);
            foreach(Cell<YUV> ch in Child.Window)
            {
                // Operation fails   
                // NullReferenceException occurs: there's no cells in `Child` neighbourhood
                wt += ch.ViabilityRatio;
            }

            Parent = Child;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to iterate over `Child.Window` I found that there's no neighbourhood elements. First what thought was that `Parent` and `Child`, especially `Child`, don't save references to objects I assigned them. I mean that `cell` variable `in the foreach loop` has not-null neighbourhood. But Parent hasn't.

### Solution 1. Helped with Parent cell

I implemented `Copy` method in `Cell<T>` class:

```
public Cell<T> Copy()
{
    return (Cell<T>)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Since then `Parent` saves its not-null `Window` property.

```
foreach(var cell in some_list)
{
    Parent = cell.Copy();
```

But `if(null == (Child = Parent.Window.FirstOrDefault(x => !(x as Cell<YUV>).IsConquered) as Cell<YUV>).Copy())` trial unfortunatelly fails.

`Child` doesn't have not-null `Window` property.

Please, Help!!
Thanks!

### Edit

I've tried to do next:

`var ActiveWindow = (from ch in Parent.Window select (Cell<YUV>)ch).ToList();`
`ActiveWindow` collection is keeping all neighbours initialized. Moreover all neighbours as I've been expecting have their own neighbours initialized.

But when I've debugged this:
`Child = ActiveWindow[0]` ... `Child` stores no neighbours..

### Edit 2

`Child` cell isn't null. I'm getting exception inside `else` clause.

This is what I got with my `Child` cell:[image]

And this is what I got with `Parent` cell:

[image]

Comment: Its the C++ monster come to eat your coding style. Omm nom nom.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't get any of this wrong, these statements make my eyes hurt :P

Say `Parent.Window` does not contain any `Window` that has not been conquered, then

`Parent.Window.FirstOrDefault(x => !(x as Cell<YUV>).IsConquered) as Cell<YUV>`

As no item matches the pattern, there is no `First`, and `default(Cell<YUV>)` returns `null`.

Reconsider this statement:

`if (null == (Child = Parent.Window.FirstOrDefault(x => !(x as Cell<YUV>).IsConquered) as Cell<YUV>).Copy())`

Would yield:

`if (null == (Child = null).Copy())`

Or:

`if (null == null.Copy())`

Since there is no object reference for the `Copy()` method, and exception would be thrown.

Comment: I have a lattice of `Cell<T>` and then I populate Array of `ICell<T>` type with variables of the lattice i.e. `Cell<T>`.

Comment: @helicera: I have updated my answer, as I believe there could be "null trouble" in additional cases with the statement you indicated. I am not familiar with your code, so it's purely C# syntax I have been looking at.

Comment: Maybe you are right saying that the culprit is my terrible statement, but while debugging I checked `Child` value and it isn't null. I'll put some image for you in my edit since it hard for me to describe what I exactly mean. Window is only the array of cells which located at 1-cell distance relative to the parent cell, so there are 8 child cells. I'm pretty sure that each cell that belongs to my lattice has filled windows.